# How to fix the spacing in a pyramid loop using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to make a pyramid loop but when the value is equal or more than 10 the shape and spacing is broken.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsend'])){
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $str = "";

    for ($row=1; $row <= $num; $row++) {    
        for ($col= $num; $col>=$row; $col--){
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }

        for ($x=1 ; $x <=$row; $x++){
            echo "<span style='background:red;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row. "&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
        }

        for ($y=$num; $y>=$row ; $y--) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
                            1                      
                         2    2                    
                      3    3    3                  
                   4    4    4    4                
                5    5    5    5    5              
             6    6    6    6    6    6            
          7    7    7    7    7    7    7          
       8    8    8    8    8    8    8    8        
    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9      
 10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

Comment: When I run it in localhost, 1 and 3 is aligned because there is a brick design in each number that's why it doesn't align when I posted it here. All is aligned well until it reaches 10+

Comment: You'll likely want [`str_repeat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to repeat your non-breaking space characters a number of times based on the [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) of your number.

Comment: Can you help me with a guide/sample code on what to do? Thank you!

Comment: You'll also need a "fixed-width" font, such as "Courier" so that things line up. Or wrap the pyramid in `<pre>` tags. This wont fix the logical errors however. It will just help you see them better.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're intending this to be displayed in HTML/CSS, you don't need to explicitly output spaces like you would to align it properly in a terminal. You can just set the number blocks to a fixed width and center them.

```
if (isset($_POST['btnsend'])) {
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $width = strlen($_POST['number']) + 1;
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $num; $row++) {
        echo "<div style='display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;'>";
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $row; $x++) {
            echo "<div style='width: {$width}ch; background: red;'>$row</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

This may not be acceptable if this is for a school assignment, but I think I'd rather use this approach if I needed to do something like this in the real world for some reason.